# Using data obtained from EXTERN opcode

Tags: assembly, global, extern

In a great endeavor towards fluency in the beautiful Assembly Language, I can't think of a better way to dip my toe into intermediate-level Assembly than to fully understand the details concerning a problem I encountered from the get-go which most likely isn't explained in my beginner's book Assembly Language Step by Step by Jeff Duntemann:

I have a file hexlib.asm which assembled and produced its hexlib and hexlib.o counterparts using the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs hexlib.asm
ld -o hexlib hexlib.o -melf_i386
```

The asm file contains the following basic code:

```
GLOBAL TestString

SECTION .data

    TestString db 'Gewurztraminer'


SECTION .bss



SECTION .text
;_start is omitted because the main.asm file already uses it. 
;I got a warning from NASM, but, like any novice, I ignored it 
;because I have enough on my mind already.
```

I also have main.asm which uses the following commands:

```
  nasm -f elf -g -F stabs main.asm
  ld -o main main.o libraries/hexlib/hexlib.o -melf_i386
```

and the code in main.asm file is as follows:
(I'm on a quest to build a machine for my company which I hope to sell, so excuse the ALL RIGHTS RESERVED dreck.

```
;#################################################################
;#################################################################
;##                                                             ##
;##            ************************************             ##
;##            *        AUTHOR: cvgbhfghfhf       *             ##
;##            *        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED       *             ##
;##            ************************************             ##
;##  _________________________________________________________  ##
;## |                   |_REGISTER_|_________CONTAINS_________| ##
;## |                   |          |                          | ##
;## | INPUT REGISTERS   |          |                          | ##
;## |                   |          |                          | ##
;## |___________________|__________|__________________________| ##
;##  _________________________________________________________  ##
;## |                   |_REGISTER_|_________CONTAINS_________| ##
;## |                   |          |                          | ##
;## | OUTPUT REGISTERS  |          |                          | ##
;## |                   |          |                          | ##
;## |___________________|__________|__________________________| ##
;##                                                             ##
;##  _________________________________________________________  ##
;## |                   |                                     | ##
;## |    DESCRIPTION    |                                     | ##
;## |    OF FUNCTION    |                                     | ##
;## |___________________|_____________________________________| ##
;## |                   |                                     | ##
;## |    PROCEDURES     |                                     | ##
;## |___________________|_____________________________________| ##
;##                                                             ##
;#################################################################
;#################################################################


;########## Build using these commands ##########

;nasm -f elf -g -F stabs main.asm
;ld -o main main.o libraries/declib/declib.o -melf_i386

;################################################


EXTERN TestString

SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data. <=============

TestStringLen equ $-TestString

SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data. <===========



SECTION .text           ; Section containing the code of procedures. <=======

    Display:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, TestString
        mov edx, TestStringLen
        int 80h

    Done:   mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h

global  _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point. <=======
_start:
    nop         ; GDB requirement. <=================================

    call Display
    call Done

;+~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*+
;* INPUT REGISTERS:                               *
;~                                                ~
;* OUTPUT REGISTERS:                              *
;~                                                ~
;* DESCRIPTION:                                   *
;~                                                ~
;+~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*+
```

When I try assembling main.asm, I get the following error:

```
~/assembly$ nasm -f elf -g -F stabs main.asm
main.asm:46: error: invalid operand type
```

Line 46 is:

```
TestStringLen equ $-TestString
```

My question is: What on earth is happening? Clearly, TestString isn't an exact replica of the TestString I initialized in hexlib.asm. Is this related to segment registers? A thorough walkthrough of exactly what is happening if segment registers are involved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your entire `main.asm`. i don't understand why line 46 would be `TestStringLen equ $-TestString` when you seem to do that on line 4.

Comment: It also makes no sense that you do `ld -o hexlib hexlib.o -melf_i386` This attempts to create a program called `hexlib` but you really only care about the object file that was already generated so you can link it later with `main.o`. Basically you don't even need to be using this command.

Comment: Regarding `TestStringLen equ $-TestString` . This won't work because `TestString` is defined in another file and its address won't be known until link time. You can't use such a value as a constant (in an _EQU_)

Comment: In your updated code you now have `TestStringLen equ $-Ten` Where is `Ten` defined?

Comment: I just changed variable names for clarity. I edited it again appropriately.
Darn! I was really hoping this was related to segment registers. I thought this would have been a great place to start. Thank you!

Comment: Seems to me what you should be doing is NUL(0) terminating `TestString` and then create a function like `strlen` that takes a pointer to a string scans the string for the nul terminator and count the characters and returning that value. The other option is creating a variable in hexlib.asm called TestStringLen and make it global and then use it in main.asm. I don't know what you are really trying to accomplish or how you will ultimately be using this in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure what any of that means. I'll have to look into all the new jargon and what they mean. You're my first welcoming to intermediate-level assembly. :) Thanks again. And thanks for the tip on the exclusion of the executable hexlib. I was just copying what Jeff Duntemann said to do until I truly understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, I've already done the latter, and it works well. I chose to do it this way to run into problems and lay down the first pavements of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> What on earth is happening?

There are two problems in your code:

**The first one** is that the given relocation type is not supported. What does that mean?

Let's have a look at the following code:

```
test1 equ 10
mov eax, test1+20
```

The assembler will create an object file (.o or .obj) from the assembler file. Within the object file the following code is stored:

```
mov eax, 30
```

Now let's have a look at the following code:

```
extern test1
mov eax, test1+20
```

In the object file the following code is stored:

```
mov eax, 20
```

And in addition a "relocation" (a special data item understood by "ld") is stored which tells the linker ("ld") that the address (or value) of "test1" must be added to the number 20 as soon as this address is known.

Depending on the file format used some operations are supported (like adding the address to a value) while other operations are not supported. Subtracting the address from a value like in `$ - TestString` is not supported by any file format I know.

So it is impossible for "nasm" to generate code for the instruction `mov edx, TestStringLen`: In the .o or .obj file this would result in the instruction `mov edx, 0` and an information that "ld" has to subtract the address of `TestString` from the value 0. However the file format does not support an entry of the type "subtract address from...".

**The second one** is that you do not know where "ld" will put the second data section.

Keep in mind that the following code ...

```
SomeText db "Test"
SomeOtherItem db "Hello"
AThirdItem db "World!"
SomeTextLength equ $-SomeText
```

... will not result in a value of 4 of `SomeTextLength` but in a value of 15. This is because `$-SomeText` means: The number of bytes from `SomeText` to **this** line. And the number of bytes is 4 ("Test") + 5 ("Hello") + 6 ("World!") = 15.

And when two lines are in different .o or .obj files you have **no control** how many bytes are "between" the two lines because "ld" may place the code belonging to different object files anywhere in memory!

So even if you used some (hypothetical) file format supporting such relocations the value of `TestStringLen` would be anything but the value you expect!

**So what to do?**

Unfortunately I don't know "nasm" but other assemblers allow generating "absolute symbols".

In this case in one file do the following:

```
GLOBAL SomeText
GLOBAL SomeTextLen
...
SomeText db "Mein Beispieltext"
SomeTextLen equ $-SomeText
```

And in the other file simply do:

```
EXTERN SomeText
EXTERN SomeTextLen
```

If "absolute symbols" are not supported you'll have to do:

```
GLOBAL SomeText
GLOBAL SomeTextLen
...
SomeText db "Mein Beispieltext"
SomeTextLen dd $-SomeText
```

And:

```
EXTERN SomeText
EXTERN SomeTextLen
...
mov EDX, [SomeTextLen]
```